How to customize `ard_continuous()` output using the cards package
I am using the R package {cards} to prepare analysis results datasets (ARDs). By default, the ard_continuous() function returns N, mean, SD, median, Q1, Q3, min, max. How can I modify the inputs to only return N and the mean?
library(cards)

ard_continuous(ADSL, variables = "AGE")
#> {cards} data frame: 8 x 8
#>   variable   context stat_name stat_label   stat fmt_fn
#> 1      AGE continuo…         N          N    254      0
#> 2      AGE continuo…      mean       Mean 75.087      1
#> 3      AGE continuo…        sd         SD  8.246      1
#> 4      AGE continuo…    median     Median     77      1
#> 5      AGE continuo…       p25         Q1     70      1
#> 6      AGE continuo…       p75         Q3     81      1
#> 7      AGE continuo…       min        Min     51      1
#> 8      AGE continuo…       max        Max     89      1
#> ℹ 2 more variables: warning, error

Created on 2024-12-10 with reprex v2.1.1

As the author of the cards package, I'd expect you to know this.  And it seems you do, since you answered your own question six minutes after posting it.

This is a response to one of the many emails I receive about the package, and I've also created the tag for the package. Now that there is a tag, I can request folks who email me questions directly to post here and I can be notified. (It isn't a nefarious point-grab!)

You can change the statistics returned using the ard_continuous(statistic) argument. The default value for this argument is continuous_summary_fns(), which just returns a named list of functions. We can specify in this function that we only want to see the N and the mean.
library(cards)

continuous_summary_fns(c("N", "mean"))
#> $N
#> function (x) 
#> length(x)
#> <bytecode: 0x1168a33d8>
#> <environment: 0x1168a7678>
#> 
#> $mean
#> function (x) 
#> mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
#> <bytecode: 0x1168a32c0>
#> <environment: 0x1168a7678>

ard_continuous(
  ADSL, 
  variables = "AGE",
  statistic = everything() ~ continuous_summary_fns(c("N", "mean"))
)
#> {cards} data frame: 2 x 8
#>   variable   context stat_name stat_label   stat fmt_fn
#> 1      AGE continuo…         N          N    254      0
#> 2      AGE continuo…      mean       Mean 75.087      1
#> ℹ 2 more variables: warning, error

Created on 2024-12-10 with reprex v2.1.1
